# Few mutations in GitHub API v4 (GraphQL)?

Tags: github, graphql, github-api

Using GitHub GraphQL API (v4), is it possible to do any of these tasks?

- Create/edit/delete repositories
- Create/edit/delete releases
- Create/update/merge pull requests
- Create tags
- Create files/blobs

We were discussing migrating to GraphQL from REST but without this functionality it seems premature. Being new to GraphQL, I want to make sure I'm not missing this functionality somewhere.

**UPDATE:**

From GitHub Staff (April 21, 2018):

> Unfortunately, mutation coverage isn’t the best in our GraphQL API
>   right now. The good news is that we have a focused team working on
>   building out parity between REST and GraphQL. It’s hard to give ETAs
>   on these mutations for you, but they’re on the list of things to do!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [createRepository](https://developer.github.com/v4/mutation/createrepository/) mutation was added to GitHub's GraphQL API v4 on [26 June 2019](https://developer.github.com/v4/changelog/2019-06-26-schema-changes/).

For example, the following mutation creates a new, public repository "foo":

```
mutation { 
  createRepository(input:{name:"foo", visibility:PUBLIC}) { 
    clientMutationId,
    repository {
      id,
      nameWithOwner
    }
  }
}
```

The [updateRepository](https://developer.github.com/v4/mutation/updaterepository/) mutation was added on [17 July 2019](https://developer.github.com/v4/changelog/2019-07-17-schema-changes/).

The ([create](https://developer.github.com/v4/mutation/createpullrequest/)|[merge](https://developer.github.com/v4/mutation/mergepullrequest/)|[close](https://developer.github.com/v4/mutation/closepullrequest/))PullRequest mutations were added on [24 October 2018](https://developer.github.com/v4/changelog/2018-10-24-schema-changes/).

Creating tags ([createRef](https://developer.github.com/v4/mutation/createref/), strictly speaking) was added on [28 June 2019](https://developer.github.com/v4/changelog/2019-06-28-schema-changes/)

So, as of 29 July 2019, I believe there are just the mutations for blobs, releases, and deleteRepository that are still outstanding from your list.